# Adding d3.js charts to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, csv, d3.js

I'm looking for some advice for adding d3.js charts to Wordpress.

My client has commissioned a forceSimulation - still in progress.  It is currently organised as follows:

- index.html
- main_javascript.js
- main_css.css
- global_properties.js
- data_file.csv

I'm totally clueless as to whether it is possible to add the chart to her Wordpress blog and if so how to do it....  Any advice would be much appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: What chart do you want to use exactly?

Comment: It's a custom d3.js chart that I've developed.  I can't show you the exact chart for confidentiality reasons but it could be any of the examples here - http://www.bmdata.co.uk/dvis.html

Comment: Or to use a Mike Bostock example - https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, [here are the WordPress docs on *Using JavaScript*](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript).

### Making it easy for them

From past experience (though not in WordPress), I'd try to simplify the steps your client has to take to get the visualisation working well, just in case the person doing them has little technical skill.

Hence, as far as possible, I'd combine your files into one `force-viz.js`:

- CSS rules can be inlined by using `d3.style` in JS on the appropriate elements.
- CSV can be inlined as a JavaScript string, parsed with `d3.csvParse`.
- `global_properties.js` can just be in the same JS file.
- `index.html` is unnecessary if you use `d3.select(...).append(...)` to construct the DOM tree you want, and instruct your client to write—

  ```
  <div id="force-viz"></div>
  ```

  —where they want the chart to appear, then `d3.select` that in your script.

This would mean all your client has to do is:

1. Place `force-viz.js` in a `scripts/` directory.
2. Paste—

   ```
   <div id="force-viz"></div>
   <script src="scripts/force-viz.js"></script>
   ```

   —into the text of any page, wherever they want the chart to appear.

### Making it easy for you

If being forced to program into a single file is annoying, I recommend [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).  It's a tool that can process a set of JavaScript files with `require('whatever.js')`-calls to each other, combining them appropriately into one file.  With [a plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/brfs), it can even turn `fs.readSync('data.csv')` calls into strings containing that file's contents, which you could use with that CSV file.

That way, you could continue programming the thing as separate files, then run `browserify` to bundle them up for your client.

Or just do it manually, if this is a one-off project.  Your call.

Comment: Thanks very much Anko.  That was exactly what I'm looking for.  Very clear and concise.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Bmil Happy to help! By the way, you can hit the check mark ("✓") at the top-left of any answer to your questions to mark it "accepted". That makes it easier for future people with the same question to find an answer.

Comment: Thank you Anko.  By